# Which version of gcm server to use for gcm - fcm migration

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

As gcm is deprecated we want to migrate our code.
As in the migration guide of google mentioned there should only be the necessity to change the endpoint from gcm to fcm for our server application. App migration was already done successful.

We are right now using com.google.gcm:gcm-server version: 1.0.0
If I see it correctly, it is not possible to change the endpoint here, as it is hardcoded into the file.

https://github.com/google/gcm/blob/v1.0.0/client-libraries/java/rest-client/src/com/google/android/gcm/server/Sender.java

On the current master there has been a change where the new FCM endpoint is used by default in the Sender class and it would also be configurable.

But there has never been a stable release with this change. There is only a 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT version.

My question is, will there be a final release before the final shutdown of gcm in April 2019. How stable is this SNAPSHOT version and is the recommendation to use it?

Or is the only alternative to migrate to the Firebase Admin SDK (which is quite a bit different than the gcm library)

Thanks

Comment: I'm also concerning this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use GCM-Server 1.1.0 version, that can be downloaded here
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.ganyo/gcm-server/1.1.0

FCM endpoint is already configured.